# Outer join on common junction table with SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of families and pet names:

```
TABLE A: Families
Smith
Jones
Chan

TABLE B: Pet names
Socks
Spot
Precious
```

And they're linked like this:

```
Table C: Family Dogs (families <-> pet names)
Smith   Socks
Jones   Spot

Table D: Family Cats (families <-> pet names)
Jones   Socks
Chan    Precious
```

My desired output is:

```
Family  Dog     Cat
-------------------------
Smith   Socks   NULL
Jones   Spot    Socks
Chan    NULL    Precious
```

This seems so simple, yet I've tried several combinations of outer joins and nothing seems to produce the output.

Comment: What is the desired output when one family has two dogs and one cat?

Comment: @CL Ah, good question. The data I have doesn't produce this situation, but I can see how it might. In which case, I don't know. I'm guessing this isn't the correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the "Pet names" table does not contain any information that is not already in the "Family Dogs" and "Family Cats" tables, so it is enough to join the "Families" table to the two link tables:

```
SELECT Families.Name AS Family,
       "Family Dogs".Pet AS Dog,
       "Family Cats".Pet AS Cat
FROM Families
LEFT JOIN "Family Dogs" ON Families.Name = "Family Dogs".Family
LEFT JOIN "Family Cats" ON Families.Name = "Family Cats".Family
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/831be/2)</kbd>

This will blow up horribly if a family has more than one dog/cat.